# Flutter does not find android sdk (installed without android studio )

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-2.3

[image: Unable to locate Android SDK]

> I have Installed android SDK without using android studio and kept in c directory
> [image: Like this]
> [image: Set Path Variable like this]
> [image: Even set flutter config --android-SDK]

Comment: `C:\Android_sdk_root\platform-tools\` add environment variable and reopen the cmdline

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `Android Studio` in order to get `Android SDK`. After you use Android Studio to get the `Android SDK`, you can continue use VScode for flutter development.

Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developer.android.com/studio and download Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I can actually download and use android sdk without android studio.

But was storing that android sdk as : "C:\ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\cmdline-tools\bin" ,

Instead It should  be stored as : "C:\ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\tools\cmdline-tools\bin"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).